# Why is it necessary to declare ros transform broadcaster in main?

Tags: ros, broadcaster, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I was trying to broadcast a tf in ros.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <tf/tf.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h> 
   
ros::Timer robot_pose_broadcaster;

void robotPoseCallBack(const ros::TimerEvent& eventalpha)
{
    tf::TransformBroadcaster robotPoseBroadcaster;
    geometry_msgs::TransformStamped robotPose;

    robotPose.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
    robotPose.header.frame_id = "/map";
    robotPose.child_frame_id = "/base_link";

    robotPose.transform.translation.x = 0.0;
    robotPose.transform.translation.y = 0.0;
    robotPose.transform.translation.z = 0.0;
    robotPose.transform.rotation.x = 0.0;
    robotPose.transform.rotation.y = 0.0;
    robotPose.transform.rotation.z = 0.0;
    robotPose.transform.rotation.w = 0.9999;
    robotPoseBroadcaster.sendTransform(robotPose);
    ROS_INFO("DONE POSE BROADCASTING");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        ros::init(argc, argv, "od_transform");
        ros::NodeHandle n;
        robot_pose_broadcaster = n.createTimer(ros::Duration(.1), robotPoseCallBack);

//      tf::TransformBroadcaster aphabetagamma;

        ros::spin();
        return 0;
}
```

This code broadcast nothing. But when I uncomment the below line.

```
tf::TransformBroadcaster aphabetagamma;
```

This code publishes transform between map and base_link even though I never use variable aphabetagamma.
Can someone help me understand this.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250808/why-is-it-necessary-to-declare-ros-transform-broadcaster-in-main?/) by [Manish Saroya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28268/manish-saroya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You create the broadcaster in every call of the callback, use it immediately and destroys it immediately. Connecting to the listeners takes some time, so it's possible that you destroy the publisher before it could send something. So create a single publisher and use it in every callback. I'm not sure how the additional broadcaster changes something.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-12-27**:
roscpp maintains publishers as singletons within the library, so creating a transform broadcaster in main has the side-effect of creating the publisher and allowing clients to connect before the second broadcaster is created in the callback.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-12-27**:
The recommended practice is to keep the broadcaster as a global with the global callback, or as a class member, and have the callback as a member of that class.